# reply time between threads [google apps script]

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to develop a script in GAS to get the reply time of all of my threads in Gmail in a specific period. The example script below seems to be a way, but im not sure on how to proceed.

```
    function processInbox() {
  // get all threads in inbox
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    // get all messages in a given thread
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    // iterate over each message
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      // log message subject
      Logger.log(messages[j].getSubject());
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use:

[Google Documentation - getDate()  GmailMessage Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getDate())

When you say you want to "get" the information, how do you want to get it?  Be sent an email?  Store it in a spreadsheet?  Record it in a .csv file?

Comment: I thought of using getDate, but i do not know on how to implement this code. It needs to get the date of the original message and the reply and calc the difference. The result could be store in a spreadsheet. The goal is to determine the average time to reply in a specific period (mont, week, etc).

Comment: If this code is just for your own use, I wouldn't put a lot of time into something like a special button to trigger the code.  If that is what you mean by how to implement the code.  You can have the code bound to a spreadsheet, and have it run automatically when the spreadsheet opens.  Is that what you mean by implementing it?  [Creating a Bound Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)